# What are the factors to consider when determining the sample size for a given study?

Tags: experimental-design, statistics

Say I'm designing a retrospective study (where I'd collect data from various schools for the last 5 years) to see if consuming milk can contribute to childhood obesity.  How do I decide on how many schools to visit? If I remember my stats correctly, in general, the goal is to achieve 95% confidence in our results, right?  So how many schools would I have to collect data from so that I will have 95% confidence in the outcome of the study?

Comment: [Related Question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/963/is-it-necessary-to-conduct-a-power-analysis-before-beginning-an-experiment)

Comment: this is a question of statistical experiment design.  The statistical power of the experiment must include all the factors you are controlling for - age, geographical region, family income etc etc.  So this really depends.  not sure this can be answered here without a lot more information.

Comment: You might consider posting this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), but as shigeta mentioned, you'd need to provide more details.

Comment: Thanks...actually that's the kind of information I was hoping to hear. The age is 5-10 years, geographical region is US, and family income is irrelevant (randomized).

Comment: Maybe this isn't the answer you're looking for... nobody who has ever done a study like this has wanted to have fewer subjects than they could get.  I'd say the answer to your question could just be 'funding'

Comment: That's a good point...

Comment: I think it depends on what type of analysis you are going to do, but I know for at least an ANOVA you can calculate the smallest sample size for a given power, but in that case you have to have an idea of how big difference you are looking to find-.

Comment: About experimental design and is a purely statistical question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about statistics, not biology.

Comment: @Remi.b Agreed, it is also far too broad for here or Cross Validated. There is an entire tag (although unfortunately populated mostly with other poor questions with no answers): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample-size

Answer (score -1):

Could be as much as possible – using multistage sampling. But it all depends on how much you are willing to spend, and your time constraint.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This does not seem to answer the question. Please add some more details and references to your answer.